# Vim syntax match first and second elements recursively

Tags: vim, syntax, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to write a set of syntax rules for matching a nestable syntax. Basically, at the simplest level, everything is either a token or a bracket. Here's an example of such a syntax:

```
[
    [a b c]
    [1 2 3]
    [foo
        [bar baz]]
]
```

I want the first element of each "list" to be colored, so in this case, `a`, `1`, `foo`, and `bar`. I also want the second element of each list to be colored, but in a different way. In this case, `b`, `2`, and `baz`. I don't care about anything else. There are no delimiters between items besides whitespace.

How can I do this with the vim pattern system? I've managed to get a simple system working, but it handles nested lists poorly. The trouble I'm having is reliably matching the *first* and *second* items of each list separately, without screwing with the other ones.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following set of rules highlights your syntax:

```vimscript
highlight       FirstToken      ctermfg=green       guifg=green
highlight       SecondToken     ctermfg=red         guifg=red

syntax region   FirstTuple      start="\(\[\_s*\)\@<=\["    end="]"
            \ containedin=FirstTuple,OtherTuple
            \ nextgroup=SecondToken
            \ skipwhite skipnl skipempty
syntax region   OtherTuple      start="\(\[\_s*\)\@<!\["    end="]"
            \ containedin=FirstTuple,OtherTuple

syntax match    FirstToken      "\(\[\_s*\)\@<=[^ [\]]\+"
            \ containedin=FirstTuple,OtherTuple
            \ nextgroup=SecondToken
            \ skipwhite skipnl skipempty
syntax match    SecondToken     "[^ [\]]\+"
            \ contained
```

The `FirstTuple` region matches tuples, of either tokens or of other tuples, that are the first in their parent tuple; `OtherTuple` is used for all other tuples. This is done via mutually exclusive lookbehinds, and proper nesting is handled automatically. `FirstToken` uses a positive lookbehind to only match at the beginning of a region. `FirstToken` and `FirstTuple` use the `nextgroup` attribute to attempt to match `SecondToken` immediately after themselves, ignoring whitespace, newlines, and empty lines. `SecondToken` uses the `contained` attribute to avoid matching everywhere by itself.

Comment: This fails on something like `[[a b] c]`. The `a` should match for the first item, and both `b` and `c` should match for the second.

Comment: You're right; I missed that case. I've entirely rewritten my answer, and besides the bug I mention at the bottom, I believe it now works.

Comment: Edited again to include the `skip*` attributes, which fix the newline issue and simplify token matching. This should work without restrictions now.